# Angular observable problems

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I've been trying to get observable's working for a bit now, but i keep failing.

At this moment, my code is starting to look more like a battlefield then the order it normally used to be.

I keep getting the "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined."

I am trying to import json data (which works), then filter out the members who are "Active" (which works), sort them alphabetically (which does not work) and get a unique list of everything that is in "team" column (which doesn't work).

The service looks as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
//import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
//import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Member } from '../class/member';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class UserinfoService
{

    //constructor
    constructor(private http: HttpClient)
    {

    }

    //methods or services

    getMembers(): Observable<Member[]>
    {
    return this.http.get<Member[]>('http://datalocation.com/JsonData/api/teammembers');
    }
}
```

the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { UserinfoService } from '../services/userinfo.service';
import { Member } from '../class/member';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material';
import { MemberdialogComponent } from '../memberdialog/memberdialog.component';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

// import 'rxjs/Rx'; // adds ALL RxJS statics & operators to Observable


// Statics
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

// Operators
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-teammembers',
  templateUrl: './teammembers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./teammembers.component.css']
})
export class TeammembersComponent implements OnInit
{

  //props
  teamMembers: any[];
  searchQuery: any = "";
  searchResults: any[] = this.teamMembers;
  teams: any[];
  selectedTeam: any;

  //constructor
  constructor(private userinfoService: UserinfoService, public dialog: MatDialog)
  {
    //getData
    userinfoService.getMembers().subscribe(teamMembers => this.teamMembers = teamMembers
.filter(member => member.isActive)
.sort((a, b) => a.lastName.localeCompare(b.lastName)));


    //put all information in results
    this.searchResults = this.teamMembers;

    //getTeams
    this.teams = this.teamMembers
    .map(item => item.team)
    .filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index)
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I got everything working when it was just a service, but the moment that i started with observables, it got all messed up.

Comment: `this.teamMembers` hasn't been populated yet when the rest of your constructor runs (because that happens asynchronously), so when you try to populate `this.teams`, you're calling `map` on an `undefined` value.

Answer (score 3):

The code inside subscription is run asynchronously.

You are trying to do a `this.teamsMembers.map` before this.teamsMembers is set by the subscription.

You should put your `this.teams = this.teamsMembers.map...` code inside subscribe lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

userinfoService.getMembers().subscribe(teamMembers => this.teamMembers = teamMembers
.filter(member => member.isActive)
.sort((a, b) => a.lastName.localeCompare(b.lastName)));

Heare you have already got the teamMembers array in component variable. so no need to required map in the later part. you can directly use the filter on the teamMembers array.

```
//getTeams
this.teams = this.teamMembers.filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index)
```

Comment: excuse my ignorance, but how do i get the value of the column team then as the result?

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand what you are asking, can you tell me what you want to get after receiving teamMembers array?

Comment: One of the columns in the table is called "team". Each team member is assigned to one of these teams. The getTeams method is to get a list that contains each team, without duplicates. The variable "teams" is then used to fill a dropdown from which the user can select.

Comment: ohk, right for that you required `.map` operator, can you use `.map` operator after getting the teams array. or just change the order of `filter` and `map` operator. first do the filter and then .map.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to move everything inside your subscribe.

Also not 100% on doing everything here in the constructor, I normally do this sort of thing in my ngOnInit but that's neither here nor there right now.

The other thing you can do is:
`teamMembers: any[] = new Array();`
This will actually initialise your array properly so that it isn't undefined.